# Joomla Calendar for versions >3.7

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, calendar

I'm trying to get a [calendar form field](https://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type) to display without using XML. For previous versions, I called JHTML::_('behavior.calendar') and initialized it with Calendar.setup({args}) that would pass arguments like firstDay, size, ... and render a input type=text and a button.

So, I wanted to add a check for versions > 3.7 to include the new Joomla calendar that has time and all the fine things I need. The problem arises because that calendar's controls are dynamic, as in, a user can choose to display the showTime for example. But I can't even find any usable info on it.

I tried with both Calendar.setup() and JoomlaCalendar.setup({}). That's throwing a function not defined. So I added jimport('joomla.html.html'). Didn't work. So I thought I'd maybe pass them as attributes to the call of calendar. Still didn't work.
For reference, I'm displaying the calendar with echo JHTML::_('calendar', defaultValue, name, id, $attributes), or however it goes.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: If anyone was ever to stumble upon this and can't find a way, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566211/joomla-calendar-3-7-version)